# How to do this pull-to-refresh in webapp?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ajax, mobile-safari, pull-to-refresh

How is the Gmail pull-to-refresh implemented?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

latest version of [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) has this built in

Answer (score 0):

Large, hidden jquery slider or draggable of some sort? I made a time picker widget using those techniques recently and it worked ok.

Comment: Aside from the fact that Google doesn't use jQuery... sure.