# JQuery Mobile : Pull to refresh list view

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, pull-to-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do this pull-to-refresh in webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950536/how-to-do-this-pull-to-refresh-in-webapp)

Is there a plugin available which will animate a list item of a list-view such that when pulled down or pulled up the list-view can be added with new list items using ajax?

I came across this plug-in which [ISCROLL 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) but I doesn't work with Jquery Mobile.

Comment: There are quite a few questions asked on the same topic but almost all had solutions where-in the implementation was not jquery mobile based, or did not work well with jquery mobile

Comment: I use iScroll in my jQuery Mobile sites. It works fine. Just make sure you are following the HTML structure of the example on the iScroll website exactly.

Comment: if you are looking for a pull to refresh on mobile check it out: https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are a few I found:

- https://github.com/svdgraaf/pull-to-refresh
- [How to do this pull-to-refresh in webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950536/how-to-do-this-pull-to-refresh-in-webapp)
- http://forum.jquery.com/topic/pull-down-to-refresh-touch-drag-to-make-server-call
- http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/08/iphone-pull-to-refresh-in-javascript/
- [Pull to Refresh Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110736/pull-to-refresh-javascript)

Comment: May I add mine : https://github.com/zippy1978/jquery.scrollz , a simple data-role is enough to make a page scrollable with pull to refresh feature. Example here :  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26978903/scrollz/mobile.html